# Load JS through php class method. Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, class

I am attempt to load a little JS code using a method php static class.
The aim is to maintain every JS on the same  place of their HTML object.
So, when we call the method it will create the HTML obj and will create a tag script  whit the $jsString inside it.
myClass 
 myMethod(){

```
  btnObjc id=txtbtnid
  $jsString="
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(\"#txtbtnid\").click(function() {
                alert(\"oook\");
            });
        });
    ";
```

}

so far so good. It creates the btn Object and create the tag script just after the btn, whit the $jsString inside it.
The problem is it is unresponsive. That means I press the button  and not is happening.
Any idea folks?

Comment: Where do you output `$jsString`?

Comment: what code is this ? is it php or some generator engine ?

Comment: the code is not complete. I have develloped a phpFramework that creates html Objects. It is part of my class. I put only the important part. I create a btn(using another method). The issue is the script tag are not recognized by the browser. If I load as separeted file it works well. But i would like to put all js after the htmlObject just created. If you want see all code, here you are

Comment: Hi Marcel i output at the end of the method $jsCode=  HTMLCLASS::HTML_JS_Code($jsString);
        return HTMLCLASS::HTML_Div(array("id"=>"div_$divNameRoot",$divTitulo.$divEscolherIdiSelect.$jsCode));

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating button after page loading

Solution:

Use **live function** instead:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(\"#txtbtnid\").live('click',(function() {
                alert(\"oook\");
            }));
        });
```

Comment: Hi Confused. I think this is the problem. Ive performed a research the .live function is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/. So I used .on. But it not works. It should.

Comment: So I think i should find a way to load the js Code after the button is created. If i load a external file it works. But if I use the JScode inside the method it not works. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: The `live` would have solved the problem if you actually have this js in your browser. It seems so that your js is never executed.